# how to select children of element by css value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selector

I have some issue here:

I want the element(s) that have `color: red` in CSS, by calling the parent of it (or them)

For example:

```
let xxx = $('.*').children().filter( function(){
  return ($(this).css('color') == 'red');
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: hi, tnx but that was not my issue..
my issue is about selecting children from css style value's of them

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of your question, you are asking for a way to *filter* just the children elements of a selected parent by selecting those with the color "red". It seems some of the answers & comments so far have misinterpreted this.

In theory, what you have done far is really close, so well done for getting this far.

The main issue is that browsers don't return the color as a string like "red"; they return it either as an RGB value or as a hex code. Hence, you will have to adapt your code to handle both cases, like this:

```
const children = $('#parent-id').children().filter(function () {
  const color = $(this).css('color');
  return $.inArray(color, ['#FF0000', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)']) > -1;
});
console.log(children);
```

Here, I've used the hex code & RGB value for the color "red".

See it in action in the following snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <style>
    .red {
      color: red;
    }
    .blue {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="parent-id">
    <div class="red">
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
    <div class="red">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const children = $('#parent-id').children().filter(function () {
      const color = $(this).css('color');
      return $.inArray(color, ['#FF0000', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)']) > -1;
    });
    console.log(children);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it workssssss.... but: :(
what if i want to get... css style >>> Right : 63%
actually color just was my example. sorry

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean "css style >>> Right : 63%"?

Comment: sorry . i mean getting this element that in css style has:
"right : 63%"

Comment: Try `return $(this).css('right') === '63%';`

Comment: it return's all childrens... our comparing doesn't work... 
note: i just replace 2th return code that you comment it. but:
" const right = $(this).css('right'); " will be useless. right?
cause it will not be use in "return function"

Comment: sorry. would may you type the whole code again.(js part)? , i just will copy that! <3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225963/discussion-between-mohsen-dayani-and-costaparas).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be like this:

```js
var nodes = document.getElementById('ID_of_parent').childNodes;
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'div') {
         nodes[i].style.background = color;
     }
}
```

Comment: very good solution, but this is javascript

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov the question **is** flagged as javascript.

Comment: @JonP, look at the syntax of the code from the author question

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, also javascript, using the jquery library. The two aren't mutually exclusive, and you can't have jquery without javascript.

Comment: @JonP, yes, of course, but it is possible for the author to use only jquery in principle :)

Comment: i've got error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

Comment: This solution attempts to *set* the (background) color of the elements, which is not what the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

HTML:

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p style="color: red">one</p>
    <p class="a">two</p>
    <p class="red">three</p>
    <p class="b">Four</p>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#wrapper').children().each((index, element) => {
  console.log(element.style.color);
});
```

Comment: tnx....will it work if my style's will be in style.css file?

Comment: if you want to get styles that are applied from the file use ```getComputedStyle```. to check more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: i've got 7 null console log... it means i have 7 child of my element. it correct. but one of them has color : red. i want the element that has this value... not the value of color

Comment: You can access the element in the loop with `$(this)` selector

Comment: actually i dont get it.... would you wrote it for me. please <3

Comment: $('#wrapper').children().each((index, element) => {
  console.log($(this)); // $(this) is the current element in the loop, you can access the current child
});

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else